# xpath to find a text box, below a specific node which in turn contains specific sub node

Tags: html, xpath

I had a hard time creating a title for this one!

Below is the example `HTML` that I'm parsing - truncated in parts for brevity, but hopefully enough for someone to understand what I'm looking for.

I'm looking to identify the `INPUT` at the very bottom of the example code.
I cannot use the `ID` because it constantly changes. i.e. `id="id_mstr111_txt"`

Let me describe in english, as best as I can, what I'm trying to get at:

> find the `INPUT`
>   ...under a `DIV` with `class="mstrPromptQuestion"`  that has as a descendant
>
> ......  span `class="mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle">Abstracted Period`

Or written another way:

> Given a `DIV` with `class="mstrPromptQuestion"` that contains a deeply embedded child node: span `class="mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle">Abstracted Period`
>   find the `INPUT` (without using the `ID` because the numbers change with every build)

I'm not sure if this is even possible with `XPath 2.0` and no `jquery` - just BASIC `xpath` functions.

```html
<div id="id_mstr85" **class="mstrPromptQuestion"** style="display: block;">
  <span class="mstrPromptQuestionRequired">
    <div class="mstrPromptQuestionTitleBar">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="left">
              <span class="mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarIndex" style="display: inline;">2.</span>
  <span **class="mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle">Abstracted Period**</span>
  <span class="mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarRequired" title="(Required)">(Required)</span>
  </td>

  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table class="mstrPromptQuestionInfoTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mstrPromptQuestionInfoCellLeft">
        <td class="mstrPromptQuestionInfoCellRight">
        </td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="mstrPromptQuestionContents">
  <table class="mstrPromptQuestionSimpleAnswerViewTitle" style="display: none;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <div class="mstrPromptQuestionSimpleAnswerView" style="padding-left: 0px;" onmousedown="this.previousSibling.rows[0].cells[0].childNodes[0].checked = true; mstr.behaviors.PromptQuestion.onClickRadio('id_mstr85', false)">
      <table id="id_mstr89" class="mstrListCart" style="display: table;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <colgroup>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="mstrListCartCellAvailableHeader">
                <table class="mstrListCartTablePathView" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <div id="id_mstr108" class="mstrSearchField" title=" style=" display: block;="">
                    <table class="mstrSearchFieldTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mstrSearchFieldSearchBox">
                            <div id="id_mstr111" class="mstrTextBoxWithIcon" title=" style=" display: block;="">
                              <div class="mstrTextBoxWithIconCaption">
                                <table class="mstrTextBoxWithIconTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td class="mstrTextBoxWithIconCellInput">
                                        <div><**input** id="id_mstr111_txt" maxlength="" onclick="if (mstr.utils.ISW3C) {this.focus();}" onkeypress="return mstr.behaviors.TextBoxWithIcon.onkeypress(arguments[0], self, 'id_mstr111', this.value)" name="id_mstr111_txt"
                                            style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" size="" type="text" /></div>
                                      </td>
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be working //div[@class='mstrPromptQuestion' and .//span[@class='mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle' and text()='Abstracted Period']]//input

Answer (score 0):

For described in english:

```
//div[@class='mstrPromptQuestion'][.//span[@class='mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle']]//input[contains(@id, '_txt')]
```

Written another way is the same, only that you specify to not use the id.

Identify a unique parent based on an attribute or based on a child and continue from there.

For above xpath you can also add a text constraint to the span like

```
 [contains(text(), 'Abstracted Period')]
```

resulting in something like:

```
//div[@class='mstrPromptQuestion'][.//span[@class='mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle'][contains(text(), 'Abstracted Period')]]//input[contains(@id, '_txt')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it's the last `input` in the `div`, you could do something like:

```
(//div[@class='mstrPromptQuestion']//input)[last()]
```

or something like:

```
(//div[@class='mstrPromptQuestion' and .//span[@class='mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle']='Abstracted Period']//input)[last()]
```

if `mstrPromptQuestionTitleBarTitle` is important.